# How to bold all vowel letters in a text with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am quite new to programming. I saw a similar example with marking specific words bold or a colour, but can't figure out how to apply it to various letters/characters. For instance, I want to take a bunch of characters and make them turn bold or another colour in any text.
Thanks in advance! Would be really grateful if you could add a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: I would be really grateful if you could attempt to solve the problem yourself, and post back with any problems you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to provide you with a complete and 100% answer because that is not how this site works but I can lead you with an example:

```
var text = 'something to replace';
var new_text = text.replace(/e/gi, ' WOW ');
alert(new_text);
```

That should be enough to get you started. Please try this out with your situation and feel free to post a question with code next time specifying the error that you receive when you try it.

Good Luck!